# Meld error when setting up a new cluster

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am evaluating the DataStax OpsCenter on a virtual machine to start managing/monitoring cassandra. I am following the online docs to create cluster topology models via OpsCenter LCM, but the error message doesn't provide much information for me to continue. The jobs status are,

```
error- MeldError, 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://[ip_address]:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/6185c776-9034-45b4-a54f-6eb9511274a2/package_information
Meld failed on name="testnode1" ssh-management-address=[ip_address]" node-id="6185c776-9034-45b4-a54f-6eb9511274a2" node-name="testnode1" job-id="1b792c69-bcca-489f-ad12-a6285ba84d59" stdout=" Meld has started... " stderr=""
```

My question is what might be wrong and any hint how to resolve that?

I am new to the cassandra and DataStax communities, please forgive me if any silly question asked!

- Q: I used to be a buildbot user and DataStax agent looks like a Buildbot's slave. Why we don't need agent setup on the remote machine to work with opscenter? The working directory of agent is configured in opscenter?

The opscenterd.log, https://pastebin.com/TJsvmr6t

Answer (score 0):

According to the compatibility of the tools set mentioned in https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html#compatibilityDocument__opsc-compatibility , I actually use the OpsCenter v5.2 for monitoring and basic db operations. After trial-and-error of .yaml of Agent and .conf of Cassandra 2.2, the Dashboard works!

Knowledge gained,

- The OpsCenter 5.2 actually works with Cassandra 2.2 which is not listed in the compatibility table
- For beginner, if not sure where to start, try to install all the components on one machine to get idea of the least viable working setup. And from there to configure the actual dev/test/production environment.

Comment: OpsCenter developer here. FYI, OpsCenter 5.2.x is end of life and no longer receives security updates. I would be quite hesitant to base your monitoring framework for open source cassandra on an end-of-life product version. Obviously my biased recommendation would be to switch from cassandra to DSE and use OpsCenter 6.1.x for monitoring, but if you want to stay on OSS cassandra then datadog, graphite, collectd, and many other actively maintained monitoring systems can be used to monitor OSS cassandra.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. I shall talk with team members to see if we need extra functionalities for Cassandra operations as other  popular monitoring tools are not designed specifically to operate Cassandra. Anyway, Ops and DSE are great products! The video tutorials are very nice!